# Why AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationName return svhost version of exe file

Tags: .net, app-config

I am using method `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationName` to get executable file name but instead of that i am getting

```
Appname.svhost.exe
```

but should be:

```
Appname.exe
```

Why it is like that?

**UPDATE**

So when when visual studio opened it is keeping `Appname.svhost.exe` for debugging purposes + `Appname.exe` if i run application. SO i closed visual studio and run app, in that case `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationName`doing the thing. But the question is is it possible to get return `Appname.exe` with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationName` when project opened? and why it is such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String ExePath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath
String ExeFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ExePath)
// ExePath = "C:\Users\You\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject\bin\Debug\AppName.exe"
// ExeFile = "AppName.exe"
```